# Probability of event depending on a variable with a given distribution

Tags: probability, density-function

Let $A$ be an event that happens with probability $1-\alpha$, where $\alpha$ has the density function $f_\alpha(x)=3(1-x)^2$ for $0\leq x \leq 1$.

Thinking analogous with the discrete case*, I came up with $$P(A)=\int_0^1(1-x)\cdot 3(1-x)^2\,dx=\frac{3}{4}.$$

Is this correct? In case, how do I show it more rigorously?

*(The probability that $\alpha=x$ is $3(1-x)^2\,dx$, so $P(\alpha=x\cup A)=(1-x)\cdot3(1-x)^2\,dx$. Integrate over $x$ to get the result.)

Answer (score 0):

You've done everything correctly, so let's just formalize.

$$
P(A | \alpha) = 1 - \alpha \\
P(\alpha = x) = 3(1-x)^2: x \in [0,1] \\
P(A, \alpha = x) = P(A | \alpha = x) \cdot P(\alpha = x) = 3(1-x)^3: x \in [0,1] \\
$$

I think part of your confusion is that the first equality is a probability mass function (which can really be interpreted as "The probability A occurs given alpha is...") and the latter two probability density functions, which in order to give probabilistic interpretations require integration, as you have done.

What you have done in this integral is marginalized the distribution, removing $\alpha$ from the distribution through integration, to arrive at the marginal distribution,

$$
P(A) = \int_0^1 P(A, \alpha=x)dx.
$$

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't think this really answers my question (it might be just me, though). What I was wondering about was more in the direction of how the result follows from axioms and definitions.

It might be that I ask for too much, that you would have to know more about the treatment in the book I use, etc. I'm not sure.

Comment: No problem G.  I was trying to rewrite your calculation in such a way that the reasoning was more clear.  The first two lines are a formulation of the problem in two distributions, one of which is conditional.  The third line follows from the definition of conditional probability, $P(A|B) = P(A,B)/P(B)$.  The final line, the marginalization, follows from the axiom of probability which dictates that the probability of a disjoint union of events is equal to the sum of the probability of the individual events.  Of course this is the continuous consequence of the axiom *waves hands*.

Comment: Although this certainly makes the solution more rigorous, part of it still appears problematic: in trying to apply your definition of conditional probability, $P(B)$ will be zero.

Comment: I don't really see this as a problem for several reasons.  First off, there's no reasonable interpretation of $P(A|B)$ when $P(B) = 0$.  Secondly, when our goal is to construct the marginal distribution, we are uninterested in the values of $B$ for which $P(B)=0$.  Thirdly, and pardon my informality but it's been a while since I took an analysis class, it's my understanding that a probability density function is really an equivalence class of functions under the equivalence relation $\int (f-g)d_{mu} = 0$, so because ${1}$ has Lebesgue measure zero we can say $f_{\alpha}(1) = 53$, and move on.